# Regular expression to delete all zeroes after first characters until the last zero in sequence

Tags: java, regex

I want to delete all zeroes coming after first letters:

Example:

```
AZ0000120003 -> AZ120003
ABDE00000DD012E04 -> ABDEDD012E04
000000A11 -> A11
```

My regexp is:

```
^[^0-9]*0+
```

So in Java I write:

```
"RE0000A3008".replaceAll("^[^0-9]*0+", "");
```

but it returns

```
A3008
```

What I need is

```
REA3008
```

How to exclude the first part of matching from result?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Just use `0+` and replaceFirst() instead of replace() all...

Comment: @Shog9 thank U for good idea. I changed my expression according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need `replaceFirst`, not `replaceAll`. Here is the proper regex:

```
0+
```

And the line would be:

```
String foo = "RE0000A3008";
foo = foo.replaceFirst("0+");
// System.out.println(foo);
```

---

To fix your original approach, you should use a replacement that backreferences a capture:

```
"RE0000A3008".replaceAll("^([^0-9]*)0+", "$1");
                           ^^^^^^^^^      ^
                           Capturing      Ref
```

Comment: But if the input is `XX1230000456` then the output should be `XX1230000456`, not `XX123456`.  Only zeroes that follow that initial block of letters should be replaced.  So this seems wrong to me.

Comment: Thank U @Unihedro. I tested, it works in all cases. It is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)0+(.*)
```

and replace it with:

```
$1$2
```

Here's a breakdown of the regex:

> **([a-zA-Z]+)** The first capturing group:
>     **[a-zA-Z]** Matches any letter, lowercase or uppercase
>     **+** Makes sure the above regex is found atleast one time
>
> **0+** Matches the literal character "0" one or more times
>
> **(.*)** The second capturing group
>     **.*** Matches any character, any amount of times

This will only match the first group of zeros, which come after a letter, and then not include them in the result.

When it is replaced with `$1$2`, that means we are replacing it with the first capturing group (`[a-zA-Z]+`), and the second capturing group (`.*`), respectively.
So, your code can look like:

```
myString.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)0+(.*)", "$1$2")
```

Here is a regex101.com test: https://regex101.com/r/kJ7bA9/1

Comment: Noteworthy is that this solution is trusty even if the input is multiline. After giving it some thought, I exceptionally liked the design because all the match will be done on one line - the broken `[^]` negated class is not used, and `.` matches all characters except newlines. So for `element\nelement\nelement`, this works on all three elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
^([A-Z]*)0*
```

and replacing it with `$1`. Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/17

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
\b([A-Z]*)0+
```

and replace w/ `$1`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH5sT1/3)